# Mule SQL Server 2012 to SSAS

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

Can Mule 4 perform ETL operations to move data from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server Analytical Services (SSAS)? If yes, does it support both Multi-dimensional and tabular data models?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but an ESB doesn't sound like the right tool to perform ETL operations - why not simply use SSIS (SQL Server Integrations Service) which should be the perfect tool for ETL between SQL Server and SSAS?

Comment: @Filburt Thanks for response. We plan to use Mule for other integration use cases as well. So are evaluating if a common tool like Mule can be used for both inbound/ outbound integration requirements and ETL as well.